# Validating double and float values using Hibernate Validator - bean validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm looking for a way to validate a `java.lang.Double` field in the Spring command bean for its maximum and minimum values (a value must lie between a given range of values) like,

```
public final class WeightBean
{
     @Max(groups={ValidationGroup.class}, value=Double.MAX_VALUE, message="some key or default message")
     @Min(groups={ValidationGroup.class}, value=1D, message="some key or default message")
     private Double txtWeight;  //Getter and setter.

     public interface ValidationGroup{}         
}
```

But both [`@Max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html) and [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) cannot take a `java.lang.Double` value.

> Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors
>   (some providers might provide some approximative support)

So what is the way of validating such fields?

I'm working with Spring 3.2.0 and Hibernate Validator 4.3.1 CR1.

Comment: If you want I can implement a DoubleRangeValidator in my collection of constraints here: http://waxolunist.github.com/validationconstraints/ - Just open an issue, you can have it tomorrow on maven central.

Comment: @ Waxolunist - Thanks but I didn't get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the annotation, but you might get false results depending. This is a general problem with doubles and imo in many cases _Double_s should be avoided. Maybe switching to a different type is the best solution? *BigDecimal* for example?

Comment: I have switched to a `BigDecimal` type but the `value` attribute of `@Max` and `@Min` only accepts a `Long` value. I need to check, if a value is between a defined range. For example, starting from 0.1 to 0.9. Is this not possible with bean validation?

Comment: For `BigDecimal` see `@DecimalMin` annotation.

Answer (score 8):

If you have switched to BigDecimal (or BigInteger), you could use [@DecimalMin](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html) or [@DecimalMax](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html).
But this is still no solution for float or double.

Answer (score 5):

I have avoided the `double` and the `float` types and implemented a custom validator that could validate a `BigDecimal` value based on the precision and the scale.

The constraint descriptor.

```
package constraintdescriptor;

import constraintvalidator.BigDecimalRangeValidator;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = BigDecimalRangeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface BigDecimalRange {
    public String message() default "{java.math.BigDecimal.range.error}";
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    long minPrecision() default Long.MIN_VALUE;
    long maxPrecision() default Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int scale() default 0;
}
```

---

The constraint validator.

```
package constraintvalidator;

import constraintdescriptor.BigDecimalRange;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public final class BigDecimalRangeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BigDecimalRange, Object> {

    private long maxPrecision;
    private long minPrecision;
    private int scale;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final BigDecimalRange bigDecimalRange) {
        maxPrecision = bigDecimalRange.maxPrecision();
        minPrecision = bigDecimalRange.minPrecision();
        scale = bigDecimalRange.scale();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object object, final ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        if (object == null) { // This should be validated by the not null validator (@NotNull).
            isValid = true;
        } else if (object instanceof BigDecimal) {
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(object.toString());
            int actualPrecision = bigDecimal.precision();
            int actualScale = bigDecimal.scale();
            isValid = actualPrecision >= minPrecision && actualPrecision <= maxPrecision && actualScale <= scale;

            if (!isValid) {
                cvc.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                cvc.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Precision expected (minimun : " + minPrecision + ", maximum : " + maxPrecision + "). Maximum scale expected : " + scale + ". Found precision : " + actualPrecision + ", scale : " + actualScale).addConstraintViolation();
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

This could be extended for other types as well, as and when required.

---

And finally in the bean, the property of the type `BigDecimal` could be annotated by the `@BigDecimalRange` annotation as follows.

```
package validatorbeans;

public final class WeightBean {

    @BigDecimalRange(minPrecision = 1, maxPrecision = 33, scale = 2, groups = {ValidationGroup.class}, message = "The precision and the scale should be less than or equal to 35 and 2 respectively.")
    private BigDecimal txtWeight; // Getter and setter.

    public interface ValidationGroup {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `@Digits` from the hibernate validator API as well

```
@Digits(integer = 10 /*precision*/, fraction = 2 /*scale*/)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's convenient in pair with `@AssertTrue` / `@AssertFalse` from `javax.validation.constraints`

```
public final class WeightBean {
    @NotNull
    private Double txtWeight;  //Getter and setter.

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean getTxtWeightCheck() {
        return txtWeight > 0.1 && txtWeight < 0.9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Hibernate Validator (at least 6.0.17) supports `@DecimalMin/Max` annotation on double

See [class for validation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/number/bound/decimal/DecimalMaxValidatorForDouble.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate validator will work for `@DecimalMin/Max` on both `Double` & `Float`. But they are not exact numbers, just approximations, depending on the validation implementation, there could be some false results.

The best idea for validation is to use the `BigDecimal` type with the `@DecimalMin` and `@DecimalMax` validation annotations.