# How can I validate a float in java? SpringMVC

Tags: java, validation

I was wandering if anyone could help me figure out how to validate a floating point. I have an annotation which validates only whole numbers and I need the input field to be able to except a decimal value, but not a 0.

Things I have tried:

```
@Range(min=(long)0.1)
```

This doesn't work and allows 0 to be passed as a valid input.
public float hoursUsed;

```
@ DecimalMin(0.1)
public BigDecimal hoursUsed;
```

I tried changing the type of the variable to a BigDecimal which I could then Validate using `@DecimalMin(min=0.1)`. However I then get an error when trying to manipulate this data.
 `"The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) BigDecimal, float"`

Trying to cast the float value to a BigDecimal results in the error
`"The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal, BigDecimal"`

I have also tried to create a customConstraintValidator annotation which would then return a validation error if the input returns a 0. That way I could Just simply use `@Range(min=0)` and a custom annotation (for example) `@NotZero` to ensure the input is indeed grater than a 0.

This results in an error in the ConstraintValidator as I can not pass in a floating point value through the generic method. The error is:
`"Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType".`

Basically my question is how can I validate a floating point?

Comment: Probably not an efficient way but you can do this in a try catch block making use of  `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I think you'll beter to check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488990/validating-double-and-float-values-using-hibernate-validator-bean-validation

Comment: Oh the joys of enterprise.  Back in the day, we would just call Float.parseFloat(), and catch any exceptions.

Comment: The question you have posted suggests switching the type to a BigDecimal, which I can not seem to do as I can not then manipulate the input as `" * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal "`

Comment: @Steve Smith i must be still living in the good old days  :) that is exactly what i suggested :)

Comment: Could either of you give me a little bit more information on how I would implement this? I need the input field to be validated and display an error to the user if the input does not pass said validation.(like `@Range` does, yet with a float).