# ConstraintValidator for single field and colection as well

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

can you tell me how to create custom constraint validator which will work for single field and collection as well?

For instance, I have an object Foo which contains the enum of status

```
public class Foo {
    Status status;
}
```

Status can be of type `active` or `disabled`. I want to ensure when I use my annotation constraint for some field of type Foo or Collection, constraint check if field/fields have set the status to the required value.

samples:

```
@StatusCheck(Status.ACTIVE)
public Foo foo;
```

or

```
@StatusCheck(Status.ACTIVE)
public List<Foo> foo;
```

Is possible to do that with a single validator? Or should I make two? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3):

I solve it using multiple validator classes defined in annotations like this:

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { StatusCheckValidator.class, StatusCheckValidatorList.class })
public @interface StatusCheck {

    String message() default "foo.message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Status value();
}
```

If you know better way how to do that feel free to add your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same validator for `Foo` and `List<Foo>`.

For that you will need to upgrade to [Hibernate Validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator) 6.0.x and [Bean Validation API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api) 2.0.1.
Then you can validate the list elements like this:

```
public List<@StatusCheck(Status.ACTIVE) Foo> foos;
```

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965678/how-to-validate-a-listbigdecimal-with-decimalmin-and-decimalmax/49966128#49966128)
for a similar problem.

You also need to enhance the definition of your `@StatusCheck` annotation
by the target `ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER`,
so that it will be allowed to put that annotation on a generic type parameter
between the `< >`:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER)
....
public @interface StatusCheck {
     ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked our version of hibernate validator and it is 5.3.x. It's large project and I can't upgrade dependency right now. Is possible to do that with our version?

Comment: @DenisStephanov No, it is not possible. You need the newer Hibernate Validator, or else the validating annotations within `< >` will be ignored.